# Concrete5 5.7: popup to get email when leaving website

Tags: email, popup, concrete5

I'm looking for an add-on on Concrete5 platform (running version 7) to help me capture email when people are leaving my website with a pop-up.
Does this exist already ? If no, is there any plan to develop this ?

Many thanks,
Matt

Comment: What do you mean by 'when people are leaving my website with a pop-up'?
And have you checked concrete5 marketplace? 
http://www.concrete5.org/marketplace/addons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably mean using what is called "exit intent"

There is one plugin that can do that: opt-in Pro (http://www.concrete5.org/marketplace/addons/opt-in-pro1/)

2 things to be aware of:
1- there are 3 versions: opt-in free, lite, and pro. Only pro offers the "exit intent" functionality.
2- A little while back some users complained that the plugin didn't work anymore, especially with newer versions of Concrete5. I don't know if that got fixed or not.

Comment: Hello Nour, thanks for your answer it's exactly what I'm looking for.